# acceder a archivo .properties en archivo .war desplegado en weblogic 12c

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, archivo-de-propiedades

Tengo un archivo `.properties` en el cual mando ciertos parámetros para que se ejecuten ciertas funciones en mi aplicación.

Lo que me gustaría saber es:

¿Hay alguna manera de acceder a este archivo .properties, editarlo  y guardarlo, sin necesidad de acceder al código fuente y replegar el war a weblogic?

Es decir, modificarlo ya desplegado en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Se podría pero tendrías que re leer el contenido del properties. Lo mejor en estas situaciones es tener los archivos .properties fuera de tu empaquetado, en una ruta específica del server y leer el archivo desde esta ubicación. Asimismo, habilitar una funcionalidad de refresco de las propiedades, es decir, de re leer el archivo y cargarlo a memoria de la aplicación.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta amigo, tendria que investigar si, estando desplegada la aplicacion en weblogic, modificando la ruta en mi fuente, puede acceder a dicho archivo, gracias

Comment: Sí se puede, te lo digo x experiencia

Comment: pues yo logre hacerlo, de una manera un tanto ordinaria pero si puedo actualizar el archivo properties sin necesidad de replegar

Comment: Sería bueno que puedas publicar tu respuesta. Así podemos aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: si amigo en la edición de mi pregunta la colocare, saludos!

Comment: No, no edites la pregunta. La pregunta es para **preguntar**. Para brindar respuestas existe la parte inferior, allí publicas las respuestas.

Comment: Acabo de revertir tu edición. Por favor considera revisar el [tour], [ask] y [answer]. Puedes ver el historial de tus ediciones para obtener el texto que habías agregado y colocarlo como una respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar la actualización de un archivo `.properties`, contenido en un *.WAR*, desplegado en un servidor de aplicaciones **WebLogic** son los siguientes, solo necesitas contar con lo siguiente:

- Archivo *.WAR* desplegado en estatus OK.
- Tener instalado **WinRar**.

Pasos:

1. Seleccionar la aplicación y realizar parada de solicitudes.
2. Dirigirse al directorio en el que se encuentra desplegada la aplicación, realizar copia,  y pegar en directorio de usuario local en *Windows*.
3. Abrir dicho archivo con **WinRar**, una vez abierto dirigirse a la ruta por defecto en donde se encuentra el archivo `.properties`, en este caso, `WEB-INF\CLASSES\“nombreArchivoProperties.properties”`, abrir el archivo con cualquier editor de texto, modificar parámetros y guardar.
4. Posterior a la edición del archivo, se copia el *.WAR* en donde se realizó las modificaciones, y se pega en la ruta en donde originalmente se obtuvo el *.WAR* descrito en el paso 2.
5. Dirigirse a la consola de administración, seleccionar la aplicación, clicar en la opción *“Actualizar”*, confirmar que la ruta de acceso de origen sea la misma en la cual pegamos el nuevo archivo *.WAR* modificado, una vez, confirmado, click en *“Terminar”*, esperar a que actualice.
6. Una vez actualizado, iniciar aplicación sirviendo todas las solicitudes y de esta manera se encuentra actualizado nuestro archivo `.properties`.